# Can WordPress post content be external data (not from the database)

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to display a page based on some data returned from an external API (Amazon). This data is formatted then, has to be displayed on a page, created on the fly, based on URL querys. I can already do this with shortcodes but this has to be from the query.

I see all kinds of info in the codex on returning custom query_posts into the loop from the database. However, I cannot find info getting external data to appear on a page.

Is this possible in WordPress? (anything is possible, right?) Just point me to some functions, filters or tutorials please.

Comment: Even if WP doesn't have API functions for this, nothing says you can't roll your own using CURL

Comment: Not sure what CURL has to do with this. I can already get the external data fine using REST. I cannot display it.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to retrieve data dynamically and display it in a WordPress page?

There are many ways to do this, but here's one option:

1. Create a [Page Template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates)
2. Create a WordPress page and use the Page Template created in step 1.
3. Edit the Page Template to call the external API and display the data

I'm guessing you've been trying to find a way to do this from the "content" of a page or post, but the easiest way is to put the code in a custom Page Template.

**UPDATE:** If you want to programmatically create a page, this might work for you: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-create-pages-programmatically?replies=5#post-1230619

Comment: Ah but I want to create the page on the fly from a plug-in I'm coding. Basically, it's an amazon search, returned to a generic page in the site. Right now I have to ask the plug-in user to create a page with a shortcode in it. That works but it also seems to be too difficult for users to understand.

Comment: Update: added a link to info on how to programmatically create a page. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.prelovac.com/vladimir/wordpress-shortcode-snippet-to-display-external-files

This is a snippet to display external data in a post.

Would this help? If the dynamic page was a HTML page and THEM displayed in WP.

Comment: Please do not just provide external links. Your answer would be worthless if the link breaks!

Comment: This is not a durable answer. If the external link disappears your answer will be of no use. Please include relevant material inline.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, Thats possible.

I Did by using bridges.

You can do it by add "add_meta_boxes" action.

Inside the meta box function you can add call and get the external page contents, or can give your own forms .etc

My Code :

```
/*
 * Add Meta Product Type Field to POST
 */

 add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'meta_box_product_type_add');
```

My Meta Box

```
/*
 * Product Type Meta Box Init
 */

 function meta_box_product_type_add()
 {
   add_meta_box('ptype_testing', 'Product Type', 'add_ptype', 'testing', 'normal', 'high');
 }

/*
 * Product Type Field
 */

 function add_ptype()
  { ?>
   <label>Type of Product : </label>
   <select name="ptype" id="ptypes">
    <option>----Select----</option>
    <option>Physical</option>
    <option>Virtual</option>
   </select>
   <label>Unit :</label>
   <select name="punit" id="units">
    <option>----Select----</option>
    <option>KG</option>
    <option>Mtr</option>
    <option>Ltr</option>
   </select>
   <?php
  }
```

Try It....