# How to fetch and display data from external API in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, api

I'm new on wordpress, and i'm trying to display datas from an external API in a specific page of my wordpress website.

I'm used to develop SPA in Angular, and usually, i fetch them on the page load (on resolve) and then display them.

I don't know how to achieve those steps in Wordpress. Should I create a page from scratch and get them in PHP, or is there any plugin to fetch  datas from external APIs, and then display them in the page section ?

What is the best way to do that ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can WordPress post content be external data (not from the database)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4937948/can-wordpress-post-content-be-external-data-not-from-the-database)

Answer (score 2):

How you go about retrieving the data is completely up to you. You can send requests to the API from the back-end in PHP using a library like [Guzzle](http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/latest/) or just use [cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) directly. Or you could send requests to the API from the front-end using JavaScript in the exact same way that you are used to using a library like jQuery (and/or a library like Angular or Knockout for data binding).

To make the requests in PHP from WordPress, you could create a custom [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#Custom_Page_Template) and populate the data from there.

To make the requests in JavaScript, you can use [wp_register_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_register_script/) to register your JavaScript snippet and then call [wp_enqueue_script](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) conditionally when the user is on the targeted page. Or you can even build the JavaScript directly into a custom Page Template.

I haven't used WordPress in years, so there may be better ways of going about this now. However, those suggestions should be enough to get you started.